# Add Scrollbar to WinForms ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, scrollbar

I have a ComboBox in Windows Form Application showing specific data from MySQL. I 
 am just wondering how to add horizontal scroll bar to my ComboBox as my data is too long to show?

Comment: Based on the accepted answer it's not Windows Forms. Please correct tags.

Comment: @Sina Updating my answer with WinForms options in a moment.

Comment: @Sina Updated answer posted, with multiple options, including dynamic width based on length of string in list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **If working with Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF):**

[ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.horizontalscrollbarvisibility(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether a horizontal ScrollBar
>   should be displayed.

Add `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"` here:

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="60,44,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="264" Height="72" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
```

For example:

[image]

Or you can navigate to the Properties of the object and select here:

[image]

### -----------------------------------------------------------

> **If working with Windows Forms (WinForms):**

If the length of your dropdowns is static, you can just set the `DropDownWidth` to a value large enough to display the full length of your list.

[image]

For example, without adjustments (the text is cut off):

[image]

For example, **with** adjustments (the text is shown):

[image]

If you need to dynamically set the width, either place the following code in your `DropDown` event handler or make it a private function/method call :

```
ComboBox senderComboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
int width = senderComboBox.DropDownWidth;
Graphics g = senderComboBox.CreateGraphics();
Font font = senderComboBox.Font;
int vertScrollBarWidth =
    (senderComboBox.Items.Count > senderComboBox.MaxDropDownItems)
    ? SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth : 0;

int newWidth;
foreach (string s in ((ComboBox)sender).Items)
{
    newWidth = (int)g.MeasureString(s, font).Width
        + vertScrollBarWidth;
    if (width < newWidth)
    {
        width = newWidth;
    }
}
senderComboBox.DropDownWidth = width;
```

For example, with dynamic width:

[image]

Comment: Question explicitly refers to WinForms, not WPF.

Comment: @kraeg A solution for WinForms is present in the accepted answer. Please take some time to see both options. When the question was originally asked (and answered), WinForms was not tagged.

Comment: Ah, so it is.  It wasn't tagged no, but it was stated in the original question. Cheers.

Comment: Should you can calling `Dispose` for the created graphics? The reference for `CreateGraphics` claims it needs to be called.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.creategraphics

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code in VB.NET:

```
Private Sub Owner_idComboBox_DropDown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Owner_idComboBox.DropDown
    For Each item In Owner_idComboBox.Items
        Dim tmpLabel As New Label
        tmpLabel.Text = Owner_idComboBox.GetItemText(item)
        tmpLabel.Font = Owner_idComboBox.Font
        If tmpLabel.PreferredSize.Width > Owner_idComboBox.DropDownWidth Then Owner_idComboBox.DropDownWidth = tmpLabel.PreferredSize.Width
    Next
End Sub
```